# Convert String type JSON to Integer with ObjectMapper

Tags: json, swift, realm, objectmapper

I have my model class

```
class CPOption : Object, Mappable
{

dynamic var optionId : Int64 = 0

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "optionId"
}

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    optionId     <- map["id"] //**Here i need to transform string to Int64**
}
}
```

Where my input JSON contain optionId as String.

```
"options": [
            {
                "id": "5121",
            },
        ]
```

I need to convert this incoming string type to Int64 in Objectmapper Map function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create custom object Transform class.

```
class JSONStringToIntTransform: TransformType {

    typealias Object = Int64
    typealias JSON = String

    init() {}
    func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> Int64? {
        if let strValue = value as? String {
            return Int64(strValue)
        }
        return value as? Int64 ?? nil
    }

    func transformToJSON(_ value: Int64?) -> String? {
        if let intValue = value {
            return "\(intValue)"
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And use this custom class in your mapping function for the transformation

```
optionId <- (map["id"], JSONStringToIntTransform())
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Helped save me time.

Answer (score 2):

there is trick to use that

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    let optionIdTemp: String?
    optionIdTemp <- map["id"]
    optionId = (optionIdTemp as? NSString)?.intValue
}
```

Comment: This works too, but it is not useful when you need to transform a big set of variables